# Text Rendering in iOS App

Tags: android, c++, ios, text, rendering

I am curious on how text rendering in application like instaweather_or InstaPlace was done?

What library that they MIGHT/ COULD be using? Because they rendered the text with some complicated symbol, like the clouds symbol and etc. It even has a little bit of drop shadows below the text.

Any thoughts? Thank you..

Please view the image below (Screenshot of the appplication)

http://img-ipad.lisisoft.com/img/1/6/1677-2-instaweather-pro.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could be embedding a custom font. 
They could also not be text, but vector art of some kind. 
SVG or other. 
In short, this could be done lots of ways. 
It could be Core Text, it could be a UIWebView or something else